# Колонки одной высоты

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Есть шаблон с 4 колонками, которые должны быть одинаковой высоты. Для решения данной задачи использую функцию:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setEqualHeight(columns) {
        var tallestcolumn = 0;
        columns.each(
            function() {
                currentHeight = $(this).height();
                if (currentHeight > tallestcolumn) {
                    tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
                }
            }
        );
        columns.height(tallestcolumn);
    }

    setEqualHeight($(".EqualHeights"));
});
```

При загрузке страницы все нормально, но при изменении ширины окна браузера текст начинает выпадать из колонок, как будто этой функции и нет. При перезагрузке страницы все опять нормально работает. Подскажите, как не допустить выпадания текста из колонок при изменении ширины окна браузера.

Comment: добавь обработчик событий при изменении размеров окна: `$(window).resize`

Comment: в чем проблема использовать flex??? зачем эти ненужные js костыли?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев проблема, как правило, в незнании.

Comment: @Regent воот. Надо было вопрос ставить иначе, спросить какие есть подходы к решению. http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/akGGVW?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

Нужно так же повешать обработчик событий .resize() на window и внутри вызывать твою функцию.

```
function setEqualHeight(columns) {
   ...
}    

$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  setEqualHeight($(".EqualHeights"));
  ...
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  ...
  setEqualHeight($(".EqualHeights"));
  ...
});
```

Подробнее про .resize() можно прочитать здесь.
https://api.jquery.com/resize/